# springboot role based access control with both two roles satisfying

Tags: java

I'm implementing a security project using spring boot. I want to allow users with both ADMIN and EXECUTIVE roles to have access to some endpoints. That is, a user must be an ADMIN at the same time EXECUTIVE user for him to access that protected endpoint. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use expression with logical `and` - `hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('EXECUTIVE')`. Using the security configuration you can do it like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/your/endpoint").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('EXECUTIVE')");
    //other configs
}
```

Comment: Very helpful indeed.